# Transfer NULL to the constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

I can not understand why the constructor is executed with the parameter `Double[]`?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            D myD = new D(null);
            Console.ReadLine();           
        }

    }

    public class D
    {
        public D(object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object");
        }
        public D(double[] array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array");
        }
        public D(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Int");
        }
    }
}
```

I think because the first constructor takes a parameter of reference type. The first constructor with a reference parameter because `null` is the default value for reference types.

But i don't understand why not `object`, it's also a reference type.

Comment: You are asking for trouble here. If you are going to use overloads, the including as general a type as object is going to lead to pain at some point

Comment: @DavidHeffernan IDK. For the most part I think which method gets called is rather intuitive. The object one only gets called if nothing else can be called. Intuitively this makes sense because the contrary would be nonsense

Comment: This is a great interview question! :)

Comment: and if you add another constructor with other reference type you will this error "The call is ambiguous"

Comment: Just follow some good practices and you will never have such a problem. In constructor you should pass dependencies a created object can't live without. So passing null is not the best practice (and not only in constructor).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> But I can not understand why no object? It's also a reference type?

Yes, both `double[]` and `object` are reference types, so `null` is implicitly convertible to both of them. However, member overloading generally favours more specific types, so the `double[]` constructor is used. See section 7.5.3 of the C# specification for more details (and boy are there a lot of details).

In particular, from section 7.5.3.5:

> Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target than T2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists

That's the case here, where `T1` is `double[]` and `T2` is `object`. There's an implicit conversion from `double[]` to `object`, but no implicit conversion from `object` to `double[]`, so `double[]` is a better conversion target than `object`.

If you want force the use of the `object` constructor, just cast:

```
D myD = new D((object) null);
```

Comment: isn't `double[]` an `object` ?

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer: Yes, so if the overload taking `double[]` *didn't* exist, it would call the overload taking `object` - but because the overload taking `double[]` is more specific than the overload taking `object`, that's the one that is picked.

Answer (score 19):

Basically, `double[]` is an `object`, but all `object`s are **not** `double[]`s. As `double[]`'s the more specific option, the compiler chooses it, as the most specific one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
double[] d = new double[] {};
Console.WriteLine(d is object);//output is True
```

double[] d is an object.

So consider this:

```
object z = new object[] {};
Console.WriteLine(z is double[]);//output is False
```

object[] z are not double[].
There is no implicit conversion from object to double[].

Comment: Whilst these are true observations, this answer on its own does not answer the question of why `new D(null)` prefers the constructor it does.